# Is there a way of handling Android notifications while the app is completely closed?

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, android-push-notification

i have a nodejs server which i use to send notifications to my android app, written in kotlin. The problem is that the notification doesn't work when the app is closed, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use services like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) or [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com) it would save you a lot of headaches